# How to sum 10 raster bands instead of 9 from code?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, raster-calculator

I want to sum 10 raster bands but the problem is that the following code will only work for summing 9 bands, which means the output image consists of 9 bands.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import os 
from osgeo import gdal
from array import *
import ctypes

entries = []
fileName = "E:/WRA/pet/mothmean81j82m.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer =QgsRasterLayer(fileName,baseName)

boh1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh1.ref = 'boh@1'
boh1.raster = rlayer
boh1.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( boh1 )

boh2 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh2.ref = 'boh@2'
boh2.raster = rlayer
boh2.bandNumber = 2
entries.append( boh2 )

boh3 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh3.ref = 'boh@3'
boh3.raster = rlayer
boh3.bandNumber = 3
entries.append( boh3 )

boh4 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh4.ref = 'boh@4'
boh4.raster = rlayer
boh4.bandNumber = 4
entries.append( boh4)

boh5 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh5.ref = 'boh@5'
boh5.raster = rlayer
boh5.bandNumber = 5
entries.append( boh5 )

boh6 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh6.ref = 'boh@6'
boh6.raster = rlayer
boh6.bandNumber = 6
entries.append( boh6 )

boh7 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh7.ref = 'boh@7'
boh7.raster = rlayer
boh7.bandNumber = 7
entries.append( boh7 )

boh8 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh8.ref = 'boh@8'
boh8.raster = rlayer
boh8.bandNumber = 8
entries.append( boh8 )

boh9 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh9.ref = 'boh@9'
boh9.raster = rlayer
boh9.bandNumber = 9
entries.append( boh9 )

boh10 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
boh10.ref = 'boh@10'
boh10.raster = rlayer
boh10.bandNumber = 10
entries.append( boh10 )

addop='boh@1+ boh@2+ boh@3+ boh@4+ boh@5+ boh@6+ boh@7+ boh@8+ boh@9+ boh@10'
print addop
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(addop, 'E:/WRA/pet/addoop.tif', 'GTiff', rlayer.extent(), rlayer.width(), rlayer.height(), entries )
calc.processCalculation()
```

Comment: I have edited your question but feel free to make changes if it doesn't reflect your problem. In regards to your question, I am not suited to answer so hopefully others can advise.

Answer (score 2):

The GDAL method (my preferred choice in this case):

```
import gdal, gdalconst, numpy

gdal.UseExceptions()




def readfile(readfilename):
    filehandle = gdal.Open(readfilename)
    band1 = filehandle.GetRasterBand(1)
    # in your case you should add extra code here...
    geotransform = filehandle.GetGeoTransform()
    geoproj = filehandle.GetProjection()
    band1data = band1.ReadAsArray()
    xsize = filehandle.RasterXSize
    ysize = filehandle.RasterYSize

    return xsize,ysize,geotransform,geoproj,band1data

def writeFile(filename,geotransform,geoprojection,data):
    (x,y) = data.shape
    format = "GTiff"
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
    dst_datatype = gdal.GDT_Byte
    dst_ds = driver.Create(filename,y,x,1,dst_datatype)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data)
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    dst_ds.SetProjection(geoprojection)
    return 1


# read files 
# do your array operations using python 
# write the files
```

Credits for Scott Arko http://www.digital-geography.com/python-for-geospatial-data-analysis-part-iii/

Personally I would do this within python using GDAL and the readasarray command. Please find such a code above.

Although it might be possible to do this with the QsRastercalculator, you can also do this with the processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', grids, xgrids, formula, result) command. However, you do need to figure out if you can read the bands rather than the entire raster.

If you work within the Qgis Python console you can easily

```
import processing

processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', grids, xgrids, formula, result)
```

In the formula you can refer to you grids as a, b and c for grid 1,2 3 etc. enter formula as string e.g. "a + b + c"

If you prefer to experiment with the tool you can also access it via the processing toolbox in Qgis directly.

for the Saga developers: The help file of this command has errors!

Comment: thax u Sir, but can i use these formula ( ( 10* band12/ band1)^ 1.52) in GDAL, In GDAL POWER() function is not give correct answer from my point of view band change in array format then how we use power() in array

Comment: Is qgsrastercalculator only work for till 9 bands in QGIS using python console...suggest me plz

Comment: In python power is done by ** maybe that will work

Comment: why qgsrastercalculator not work from 10 bands??